# Mirror / cast / live stream desktop screen to TV over LAN

Tags: display, desktop-recording, desktop-sharing, smart-tv

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and looking for a way to live cast / stream / mirror my desktop (only Firefox tabs actually) to my LG TV (WebOS v5.30) over LAN.

Note (in case it's useful to give you more ideas to help me): besides the smart TV itself, I also own a Fire Stick 4K and it's connected to it! I also have Kodi on it.

This is what I've already tried with no success:

- [NetworkDisplays](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.NetworkDisplays) via Flatpak - no Video Sinks available
- [Deskreen](https://deskreen.com/) - via the TV browser app, I could connect to the desktop but the screen was so small that it was unusable
- VLC on Ubuntu + VLC on my Fire Stick. I tried to follow [these](https://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/27/tutorial/share-screen-using-vlc-over-local-network.html) instructions, but when I entered `udp://[my_PC_IP]:[port]` in the VLC Fire Stick app nothing happened
- Installed [AirScreen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CPZ698R) on my Fire Stick and the *Cast* method in Chromium worked fine (I could mirror a Chromium tab to the TV) but that's not enough for me, since I need to do that in *Firefox* actually :)

Could you please help me in finding other working methods to try (or provide some tested and working instructions for any of the methods above that I've already tried)?

Thanks

Comment: Is it too far away to just output the video from your PC via a HDMI cable to the TV? (I'd always try the simplest solutions first :))

Comment: @raj yes already thought about that, it's too far :(

Comment: Optionally, if you have a free (unused) LAN cable between the two locations, you can consider using a HDMI-over-Ethernet extender (you need to buy them of course). The range is up to 70 meters for 1080p resolution, up to 40 meters for 4K.

Answer (score 0):

Does your TV support Chromecast? If so, you can use a Chrome based browser. Click the three dots in the top right corner and click Cast. Change the Sources field to Cast Desktop and select your TV.

Cast desktop to smart TV:

[image: Cast desktop to Smart TV]